# switch string statement not working?

Tags: c#, tcpclient, tcp

$I already convert the data i receive. but when i try to put it in a switch statment, it dosent do anything. as you can see there is a MessageBox.Show(rData) which shows the data i receive and its good. only on the switch. any suggestion?

```
    string readData = null;

    public void getMessage()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
            int buffsize = 0;
            byte[] inStream = new byte[10025];
            buffsize = clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize;
            serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, buffsize);
            string rData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream);
            readData = "" + rData;
            //MessageBox.Show(rData);

            switch (readData)
            {
                case ("Overview"):
                    MessageBox.Show("Start");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean "it is good"? What *precicely* is the value of `readData`?

Comment: "data is good" is not enough. Please provide true [MCVE] along with all necessary data inline.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you are new user, I recommend you read ["How to Ask a Good Question"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Asking question properly will help you get better answers and help others be able to understand your question if they have a similar problem.

Comment: Is readData equals "Overview", caps and all? What's your rData value?

Comment: Are you sure the commented out MessageBox line displays Overview with no spaces or additional characters (incl. Null) after it? What's ReceiveBufferSize? If more than 8 then it won't match "Overview".

Comment: Also, you make your `instream` byte array size 10025, but set `buffsize` to `clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize`. If those are not the same size you could potentially have issues on this line `serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, buffsize);
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
byte[] inStream = new byte[10025];
```

you have initialized a byte array of with length 10025. If your incoming data is not that long you will get bunch \0 characters (string terminator) at the end when you convert it into string.

Those characters will not show up when you called MessageBox.Show since they are invisible characters.

so the solution is to initialize the array to the size of the actual data

OR call `.Replace("\0", "");` on the string before you feed it into the switch statement

Comment: can u be more specific to where should i put those? var.Replace? or?

Comment: @Jss readData = readData.Replace("\0", ""); before the switch

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that (I assume) you are using C# 7.0 and you are attempting to match case on a [value tuple](https://www.grapecity.com/en/blogs/tackling-tuples-understanding-the-new-c-7-value-type/) (which you are accidentally constricting using the parentheses around your string in the case statement). Remove the parentheses in your case statement and try again.